# Use OpenTelemetry for distributed tracing with TSOA

Tags: express, open-telemetry, tsoa

Has anyone had experience incorporating OpenTelemetry into a TSOA, Express, and Node.js? I've been searching for examples but haven't found any. I'd greatly appreciate hearing from anyone who has worked on a similar integration.

The objective is to develop a decorator or middleware solution for managing traceId and spanId.